# Filtering Pandas rows based upon values in a column existing in a list, where the column name is a variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filtering

I'm trying to create a function that will filter a dataframe based upon column entites existing in a list.

If the column name was always going to be the same (in this case 'COLUMN_NAME'), then to select all rows in which that column value existed in FilterList would be simply;

```
df = df[df.COLUMN_NAME.isin(FilterList)]
```

What if the COLUMN_Name was variable though?

I tried simply using a string representation as follows;

```
filtertxt = 'df.'+ColTarget+'.isin(FilterList)'
df = df[filtertxt]
```

But that didnt work. Could anyone else suggest how to generalize the DF filtering above to allow me to pass the target column to filter as a variable?

Thanks

Comment: Use brackets in that case: `df[ColTarget].isin(FilterList)`

Comment: if possible avoid dot notation for DataFrames, it's easier but less explicit as they can be confused for methods in the pandas API.

Answer (score 0):

Erfan supplied 95% of the answer. The suggestion;

> Use brackets in that case: df[ColTarget].isin(FilterList)

Just returns a binary filter dataframe, so the final code to return the filtered dataframe would be;

```
df[df[ColTarget].isin(FilterList)]
```